# Is it possible to do x64 bit software engineering in 32 bit based pc?

Tags: 64-bit, software-design, 32-bit

I want to be a software engineer. I have both **32** bit and **64** bit based pc. But i wondered, is it possible to make 64 bit softwares in 32 bit based pc? If not, then what can be alternative?

Comment: Define "make"... are you talking about developing software? compiling it? And what do you mean by "64 bit software"?

Comment: @Sneftel i meant softwares which run only in 64 bit architecture.